# Create key and value in SSM parameter using if condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I need to store the respective values in ssm according to my condition and the key is same for all the 3 environment i.e dev, SI and prod.
The template section for SSM is:

```
Parameters:
  AccountEnv:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Default: '/account/environment' (which store the envtype)

Conditions:  
  IsFirstRegion: !Equals [!Ref "AWS::Region",us-east-1]
  IssecondRegion: !Equals [!Ref "AWS::Region",us-west-1]

    Mappings:
      DomainMap:
        development:
          firstRegion: "local-application-logs"
          secondRegion: "local-2d-application-logs "    
        systems-integration:
          firstRegion: "local-si-application-logs"
          secondRegion: "local2s-application-logs"
        production:
          firstRegion: "local1p-application-logs"
          secondRegion: "local2p-application-logs"
    
        ROSALOGGROUPDev1:
             Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
             Properties:
               Name: local/logs/loggroupname
               !If: IsFirstRegion
               Type: String
               Value: !FindInMap [DomainMap, !Ref AccountEnv, firstRegion"]
               Description: sample loggroups to store
        ROSALOGGROUPDev2:
             Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
             Properties:
               Name: local/logs/loggroupname
               Type: String
               Value: !FindInMap [DomainMap, !Ref AccountEnv, secondRegion"]
               Description: sample loggroups to store
```

I need to store the log group values according to my Environment and AWS Region, as this is not working because template is not correct. What can I do here to satisfy this if condition?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. this is invalid template.

Comment: Also you need to develop a macro for what you want to do. Or simply change your architecture, to not require this key parameter.

Comment: Any suggestion would be great .I know template in invalid I just trying to know the logic either using if condition if possible

Comment: Do you only have two regions?